# Calculating ratios for contrasts after lmer model

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, contrasts, lsmeans

I have performed `lmer` on my data and, to be generic, my model has 3 fixed effects (A,B,C) and 3 nested random effects (d,e,f) following the response variable y: `y~A * B * C+(1|d/e/f)`.

I also ran `lsmeans(mymodel, specs=~ A|B:C)` and I'm interested in seeing the radio contrasts instead of the linear / quadratic contrasts. For example, if `A1` and `A2` are levels of fixed effect `A` and `B1` and `B2` are levels of fixed effect `B` (`C1` & `C2` are levels of fixed effect `C`), I'm interested in calculating the estimate and pvalue of `(B2-B1)/B1` at `A1` and `C1`.

How can I accomplish this? I usually define my own contrast by making a matrix but that is a "linear" approach.

---

So as a follow up question, the pvalue is naturally very large because I'm limiting the difference to the absolute value. Is there a way to get the actual factor difference `(A-B/A)` instead of `(|A-B|/A)`.

I'm using `mvt` for multiple comparison but is this the least stringent one? I would rather have false positives than false negatives.

Answer (score 6):

It is doable! You have to do it in stages, though. Using the `warpbreaks` data to illustrate, I'll do such comparisons of `wool` at each `tension`:

```
> warp.lm = lm(breaks ~ wool * tension, data = warpbreaks)

> library(emmeans)
> (warp.emm = emmeans(warp.lm, ~ wool | tension))

tension = L:
 wool   emmean       SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 A    44.55556 3.646761 48 37.22325 51.88786
 B    28.22222 3.646761 48 20.88992 35.55453

tension = M:
 wool   emmean       SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 A    24.00000 3.646761 48 16.66769 31.33231
 B    28.77778 3.646761 48 21.44547 36.11008

tension = H:
 wool   emmean       SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 A    24.55556 3.646761 48 17.22325 31.88786
 B    18.77778 3.646761 48 11.44547 26.11008

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

The second stage is to set up the numerators and denominators:

```
> (custom.emm = contrast(warp.emm, list(`A-B` = c(1, -1), A = c(1, 0))))

tension = L:
 contrast  estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 A-B      16.333333 5.157299 48   3.167  0.0027
 A        44.555556 3.646761 48  12.218  <.0001

tension = M:
 contrast  estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 A-B      -4.777778 5.157299 48  -0.926  0.3589
 A        24.000000 3.646761 48   6.581  <.0001

tension = H:
 contrast  estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 A-B       5.777778 5.157299 48   1.120  0.2682
 A        24.555556 3.646761 48   6.734  <.0001
```

Now, use `regrid()` to fake a log transformation, needed because differences of logs are logs of ratios. Thus, we get the differences and back-transform them:

```
> pairs(regrid(custom.emm, transf = "log"), type = "response")

Non-positive response predictions are flagged as non-estimable
tension = L:
 contrast     ratio         SE df t.ratio p.value
 A-B / A  0.3665835 0.09688534 48  -3.797  0.0004

tension = M:
 contrast     ratio         SE df t.ratio p.value
 A-B / A     nonEst         NA NA      NA      NA

tension = H:
 contrast     ratio         SE df t.ratio p.value
 A-B / A  0.2352941 0.18695686 48  -1.821  0.0748

Tests are performed on the log scale
```

Note that we need to re-run `custom.emm` with the first contrast reversed to get the result for medium tension, because the log transformation choked on the negative difference.

A couple of misc. notes: I used the new **emmeans** package, which is just out and succeeds **lsmeans**. If you still like the term "least-squares means", you may use `lsmeans()` instead of `emmeans()` and it will do the same thiong with different labels attached. Also, this does also work with the existing **lsmeans** package, except the final results are labeled a bit differently.

#### Addendum

Here's a way to get them all at once:

```
> custom.emm1 = contrast(warp.emm, list(`|A-B|` = c(1,-1), A = c(1,0)))
> custom.emm2 = contrast(warp.emm, list(`|A-B|` = c(-1,1), A = c(1,0)))
> custom.emm = custom.emm1[1:2] + custom.emm2[3:4] + custom.emm1[5:6]
> custom.emm
 contrast tension  estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 |A-B|    L       16.333333 5.157299 48   3.167  0.0161
 A        L       44.555556 3.646761 48  12.218  <.0001
 |A-B|    M        4.777778 5.157299 48   0.926  1.0000
 A        M       24.000000 3.646761 48   6.581  <.0001
 |A-B|    H        5.777778 5.157299 48   1.120  1.0000
 A        H       24.555556 3.646761 48   6.734  <.0001

P value adjustment: bonferroni method for 6 tests 

> test(pairs(regrid(custom.emm, tran = "log"), by = "tension", type = "response"), 
       by = NULL, adjust = "mvt")
 contrast  tension     ratio         SE df t.ratio p.value
 |A-B| / A L       0.3665835 0.09688534 48  -3.797  0.0012
 |A-B| / A M       0.1990741 0.23724291 48  -1.354  0.4477
 |A-B| / A H       0.2352941 0.18695686 48  -1.821  0.2057

P value adjustment: mvt method for 3 tests 
Tests are performed on the log scale
```

The Tukey method won't be allowed here because these aren't recognized as pairwise comparisons; but the mvt method is the moral equivalent of the Tukey adjustment. Using the `+` operator to do `rbind()` is a new feature in **emmeans**.

By the way, don't put whitespace around the `-` in `|A-B|` -- it will turn the labels into `|A / B| / A`

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! So if I wanted to gt the medium tension,  I should reverse the contrast matrix so that it would be (B-A) and then rbind this with the results from pairs(custom.emm) to get the pvalue adjusted for multiple comparison? Or is should I run the test() again on the combined matrix?

Comment: Yes, something like that. You need to do something like `rbind(pairs1[c(1,3)], pairs2[2])` with the two results from `pairs()`